# Monitoring Serial Console with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, serial-communication

I have an application write on C# that need to wait a response to continue the flow, is a type of console that communicate with a embedded system with linux that use serial console. The application sends a command through the serial port and needs to wait a response from the command, the actual problem is that the commands has different times to send response, because this i'm avoiding the use of timers . I have de follows configuration:

- One text box that logs all commands and responses. This textbox is updated through bidding of StringBuilder variable;

I tried, unsuccessfully, to polling the StringBuilder variable used to update the text of TextBox using a Regex to filter the text, but the StringBuilder variable grows up and this method becomes inefficient and don't work.

Anybody have a suggestion that how can i wait for this response to update the test status?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Serial ports are pretty slow but, yes, you can still easily get a modern machine to its knees with the UI thread burning 100% core if you just blindly append text to a text box.  And totally overwhelm the user's ability to keep up reading the received data.  Which is of course the ultimately flaw in your UI, it is just useless to a human.  Being able to freeze the display and look through snapshots is essential.  And trivially solves the perf problem.